# Suppress message from Bitbucket remote when pushing commits

Tags: git, bitbucket, push

Is there a way to suppress this message I keep getting every time I push a commit:

[image]

Obviously it's an important message that I should see at least once, but I've already determined I personally don't need to worry about it. I push commits all day and every time I see it I think I just did something horribly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

29th is a Sunday, 28th is Saturday, this leaves you with just one day to suffer. You'll be fine ;)

*(Yes, I'm assuming you only push during the working week)*

***Update**: the assumption was wrong.*

You could grep the output:

```
git push 2>&1 | grep  -v -e "We're" -e "your firewalls" -e "3707"
```

Comment: Your assumption is a bad one, grad students have 8-day work weeks. I also want to know for future use.

Comment: @adamconkey In this case let's make `grep` do some work.

Comment: All the lines start with "remote: ". If it's critical that you ignore any message like this, then pipe your push to `grep -v -e "remote: "` and that should do the trick.